# How to pass optional selected text to a task

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to run a task and optionally pass in any currently selected text, ignoring the argument if there is no selection.

For example:

```
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo",
        "args": [
            "${selectedText}"
        ],
    }
```

The above task will run fine if there is a selection, but VS Code gives an error and refuses to run the task if there is no selection. I've tried using an input:

```
"inputs": [
    {
        "type": "promptString",
        "id": "selection",
        "description": "Selection:",
        "default": "${selectedText}"
    },
]
```

I then pass "${input:selection}" to the task. This prevents the error message from VS Code if there is no selection, but then Terminal hangs and the task does not complete.

Answer (score 2):

v0.3.0 of the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) has a version of `selectedText` that returns an empty string when nothing selected.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo",
      "args": [
        "${command:extension.commandvariable.selectedText}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: vscode now support this as a proper variable

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables

Comment: @MadhusoodanP That variable was there already but we need: `returns an empty string when nothing selected`